# How to drop an item in Fortnite on Mac?

Tags: macos, fortnite-battle-royale

On PC it's <kbd>X</kbd> to drop a weapon, so that a teammate can pick it up. How do I do that on Mac?

Comment: I'm not sure since I play on Windows, but I believe that in the inventory bottom it's showing the controls you should use to drop, drop half, and all that.

Comment: @Brhaka thanks, i had to press Tab and bottom controls are seen there

Answer (score 0):

When you open you're inventory screen, instead of pressing anything, you can just drag and drop the weapon outside the inventory screen. At least that's how I drop stuff, there might be something easier, but this works.